# Converting analogue data to an array for filtering in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, filter, sensors, lowpass-filter

I am readingdata from a sensor but wanted to filter the data for every 2 sec samples(The data is very noisy).
From various sources on the internet, it seems only be possible to filter data from an array. 
How can I store the data into an array (10 data points) every 2 seconds in C#.The temperature data is a double value.

```
double analogDataIn = reader.ReadSingleSample();
double analogTemp = (analogDataIn * 100) - 50;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a `List<double>` adding values until you have a list length of 10. Then simply call `List.ToArray()`

Comment: Like this?                                                                                                     
          for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
     list.Add(analogTemp);
       
    }
  double[] s = list.ToArray();

Comment: @damu_d every time you read in an anlalogue value add it to the list. Then check with `if(List.Count == 10)` if you have enough values. And don't forget to clear the list.